# Get all paths of matching jsonpath filter

Tags: postgresql, jsonpath

I'm using PostgreSQL 14.

I need to find all paths that matches the jsonpath filter I give.

**Input example**

```json
{
  "A": [
    {
      "B": [
        [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "conditions": [
              {
                "validator": "nonnull"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "x",
            "conditions": [
              {
                "validator": "required"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "y",
            "rules": []
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "name": "z",
            "conditions": [
              {
                "validator": "required"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**JsonPath filter**

Every A.B which has a required validator condition:

```
$.A.B[*].conditions ? (@.validator == "required")
```

**Expected output** (Or something close)

```
{A,0,B,0,1,conditions,0}
{A,0,B,1,0,conditions,0}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a *relational* solution, you may define the query as a view and filter on the `validator` and you get the array indexes.

```
select a.index-1 as a,
b.index-1 as b,
b2.index-1 as b2, 
c.item ->> 'validator' as validator,
c.index-1 as conditions
from t cross join 
jsonb_array_elements(jsn -> 'A') WITH ORDINALITY a(item, index) cross join 
jsonb_array_elements(a.item -> 'B') WITH ORDINALITY b(item, index) cross join 
jsonb_array_elements(b.item) WITH ORDINALITY b2(item, index) cross join 
jsonb_array_elements(b2.item -> 'conditions') WITH ORDINALITY c(item, index);

a|b|b2|validator|conditions|
-+-+--+---------+----------+
0|0| 0|nonnull  |         0|
0|0| 1|required |         0|
0|1| 0|required |         0|
```

Comment: Well, that's actually my initial solution, I hoped I could find a more optimized solution. Thanks anyway!